# Ruby: Pair individual values of two arrays into third array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays: `['x','y','z']` and `[1,2]`.  How would I go about creating pairs of values (as a string) in a third array?

So I would end up with this:

```
['x:1', 'x:2', 'y:1', 'y:2', 'z:1', 'z:2']
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-product) method to create the pairs and then [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) them:

```
a1 = ['x','y','z']
a2 = [1,2]
a1.product(a2).map {|p| p.join(':') }
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to split the problem into two separate problems. In this case, the following:

1. iterate through each element on both arrays at once. pushing in the values as we go.
2. place the string into a branch new array.

While messy, I would perhaps do something along this path:

```
def foo
  #declare our known values as arrays, and initialize the container of the final result.
  combined_array = []
  array_letters = ['x', 'y', 'z']
  array_numbers = ['1', '2']

  array_letters.each do |letter|
    array_numbers.each do |number|
      combined_array << "#{letter}:#{number}"
    end
  end
  #return our new array
  combined_array
end
```

Now mind you, I am sure there is a better way to do this. But in consideration, I am fairly certain this should work.

Comment: It works, but it is not a Ruby way. It is the old school way. I won't downvote, but I won't upvote either.

Comment: never said it was, hence me saying at the very end that there is surely a better way to do this.
And this is the case, as demonstrated by Phil.

Comment: I posted before I saw the answer Phil gave, by the time I posted, Phil had also posted. Therefore, my page updated with both my answer and Phil's.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that's short and efficient, and reads well.

```
a1 = ['x','y','z']
a2 = [1,2]

a1.flat_map { |e| a2.map { |f| "#{e}:#{f}" } }
  #=> ['x:1', 'x:2', 'y:1', 'y:2', 'z:1', 'z:2']
```

I originally had `a2.map { |f| e.to_s+?:+f.to_s }`. I replaced `flat_map` with `map` and `e.to_s+?:+f.to_s` with `"#{e}:#{f}"`, as suggested by @PhilRoss and @Stefan, respectively. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: `a2.flat_map` could be replaced with `a2.map` (the result is already flat).

Comment: I'd use string interpolation `"#{e}:#{f}"`